# Public User Profile Page

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to incorporate a public profile page for my website. Basically I have the database all setup and editprofile and stuff. Its all working 100% properly including changing your picture.

What I want to do is make this file "profile.php" make it so that if you goto a link like this for example.

http://local.com/profile.php?id=8

It will bring you to the user with the userid 8 and show the information.

I'm thinking that I could just make it SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$userid'.

I use the $id for the userid of the person viewing the page but I have to make $userid a variable that holds the id of whatever profile you're viewing.

Next I could do something like this

```
$id=$_SESSION['id'];
$result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users where id='$userid'");
while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3))
{ 
$username=$row3['username'];
$email=$row3['email'];
$firstname=$row3['firstname'];
$lastname=$row3['lastname'];
}
```

I guess my question is how would I make it so $userid is equal to whatever profile you're viewing and make it so the link profile.php?userid=8 would bring you to user 8.

Anyone got ideas? :)

Comment: `editprofile and stuff. Its all working 100% properly including changing your picture` Wow are you sure you have the rest all working and yet you don't know how to use `$_GET['id']`?

Comment: I have been coding all day since 9AM and its now 1:05AM. I am not thinking very clearly and my heads hurting but I just wanted to finish this up before I get to bed.

Comment: @Prix - On the curve using the deprecate library as well.

Comment: @KevinHarrison - What creature are you with multiple heads? Please, dear, go to bed.

Comment: Thankyou @Prix!

@EdHeal I just started learning PHP this week and I'm working on a big PHP project for the next few days. Its not too important but the only way to learn is by jumping in and trying everything. If I just read a textbook then never made anything I wouldn't learn to much. Sorry if I come off as some noob.

Comment: @KevinHarrison - Why not learn to walk before doing the Olympics? Saves you doing a Paula Radcliffe

Comment: I completed the PHP course on CodeCademy a couple days ago so I did learn about PHP just not much about MySQL. This is my first project since learning PHP. Its not a big project, its just a basic social network.

Comment: @KevinHarrison if you just started learning then you should stop copying and pasting code and actually read the things around so you just don't end up with a huge copy and paste and instead actually learn it. You're missing too much important information at this point from your question. POST and GET methods are common PHP methods and not MySQL.

Comment: I already know what POST and GET methods are. I just mixed them up by accident thats why I thought GET grabbed cookie data when you guys said it. And I'm not copying and pasting code at all. My goal isn't to finish the project. My goal is to learn how to finish the project. Each step along the way I have to read a lot online and thats the best way for me to learn. I am more hands-on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shortest answer is

```
$userid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$result3 = mysql_query(....);
//....
```

The longer version of answer is that, you shouldn't use mysql_query because it is deprecated and will be removed at the newer version. You can move to PDO or mysqli. Let say that you want to stick with legacy function mysql_*, you need to use `mysql_real_escape_string` to protect yourself from SQL Injection. However, inproper use of `mysql_real_escape_string` will cause you to invulnerable to the injection.

Comment: Wouldn't $_GET['id'] grab the id of the user signed in?

Comment: No, $_GET['id'] will grab the input from the link. For example: http://localhost/profile.php?id=8 <-- this

Comment: Thankyou! Thats working perfectly and if I echo $username it shows the correct data! Thanks! By the way what do you mean by PDO and mysqli? How would I convert it to that. I only started learning PHP this week and I don't have much experience with MySQL. This is my first big PHP project. But hey, we all have to start somewhere, right? I would appreciate if you could inform me about PDO and mysqli but I understand if you don't have the time. None the less thankyou for your help!

Comment: @KevinHarrison, as a starter and have already started your project. I suggest you to learn about "SQL Injection" first. Then, you can try to learn PDO for your next project.

Comment: I actually am pretty good with SQL injection. I learned SQL injection about 9 months ago and thats how I know a little bit about MySQL. As I said before I never learned MySQL but I know a bit because of SQL Injection. I've heard of mysqli and I know what it is but what is PDO and how does mysqli and PDO stop SQL Injection?

Note: I learned SQL Injection, but that doesn't mean I was very good at it. I just have a bit of experience.

Comment: @KevinHarrison, it would be a long answer. The shortest answer that I can tell you is that PDO and MySQLi does not totally prevent SQL injection. However, it provides better mechanism to help you fight against SQL injection (for example: prepare statement). Manually concatenate SQL query is the root of "SQL Injection". With `prepare` statement, the SQL query and data will be sent to MySQL separately.

Comment: Yeah I think I read about that a while ago. I remember something like this:

$db->prepare("insert into");

Do you think you could point me in the right direction of where I could read about PDO and MySQLi?

Comment: @KevinHarrison: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly/

Comment: Although I have one quick question.

Would it be possible to SELECT * FROM Table1, Table2.

Do you know what I mean? I want to select all from two tables and save it as $result3.

I did try it on my own with SELECT * FROM `users`, `photo` and SELECT * FROM users,photo. Not 100% sure and I can't find anything on Google.

Answer (score 0):

`$_GET['$variable'];` use this method to fetch data from URL bar. And if you are using post method in your form so then use `$_POST['$variable']`;